# i.imgur.com always returns status code 404

Tags: windows-7, http-status-code-404, imgur

I keep getting 404 error codes when I try to go to i.imgur.com. Using different browsers or incognito mode doesn't help. However, when using the my phone (on the same network) I can reach it fine. Also, I tried with a virtual machine and it also worked. Any ideas of what could be the cause of this?

I am using Windows 7, thanks!

Comment: i.imgur.com redirects to imgur.com. So you can access imgur.com but not i.imgur.com?

Comment: I think imgur.com serves the html, js and css files, while the actual images are served from i.imgur.com (which is a CDN)

Comment: Reporting back. The problem was that I had modified my hosts file a few months back (to solve some other issue) and I forgot about it. Then i.imgur.com IP address changed and that caused my problem. Reverting my hosts file changes solved the issue.

So if you have a similar problem in Windows, check %SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

Comment: Glad to hear you resolved the problem. You should post your solution as an answer and then accept it so that this question is marked as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reporting back. The problem was that I had modified my hosts file a few months back (to solve some other issue) and I forgot about it. Then i.imgur.com IP address changed and that caused my problem. Reverting my hosts file changes solved the issue. So if you have a similar problem in Windows, check %SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts